Would Deut 33:20 be considered an example of compound indefinite direct objects in Hebrew?
The Hebrew for Deuteronomy 33:20 reads:
וּלְגָד אָמַר בָּרוּךְ מַרְחִיב גָּד כְּלָבִיא שָׁכֵן וְטָרַף זְרוֹעַ אַף־קָדְקֹד
The English translation (KJV) for Deuteronomy 33:20 reads:
And of Gad he said, Blessed be he that enlargeth Gad: he dwelleth as a lion, and teareth the arm with the crown of the head.
From my understanding of the English translation, "arm" and "crown" are both direct objects of the transitive verb "teareth." Is this an accurate assessment, and does this hold true for the Hebrew text (i.e., Is it fair to say that "זְרוֹעַ" and "קָדְקֹד" are compound direct objects of the verb "וְטָרַף")? Also, is there an official term for verbs that act on compound direct objects? Thanks!

I don't know about the Hebrew, but your English analysis is wrong. Crown is not a direct object. You should think of it as either an indirect object or a prepositional phrase. (If it was a direct object, we would be tearing the crown itself. But here only the arm is torn.)

@PeterKirkpatrick Is it that crown is not a direct object, or is it that the KJV is coming across vague here? My assumption was the latter. If you look at other English translations of Deut 33:20 (e.g., NIV, NLT, ESV & even the NKJV), the case for the word the KJV renders crown also being a direct object is much stronger. The Hebrew word אַף־ that the KJV renders with is rendered or/and in other English translations. אַף־ means "also, yea, how much more etc." Wondering if someone fluent in Hebrew would say that the actual Hebrew reads the same way many English translations render this.

Yes
וְטָרַ֥ף‬ זְרֹ֖ועַ אַף‬־קָדְקֹֽד
(BHS2003)
זְרֹ֖ועַ אַף‬־קָדְקֹֽד
is a compound direct object of
טָרַ֥ף‬
אַף
is an interjection such even, also.
Thus, "To tear off arm and scalp." (JPS1985)
References

The direct object is the object (person or thing) affected directly by the action of the verb. In “he threw a ball,” the direct object is “a ball.” --
Futato, M. D. (2003). Beginning Biblical Hebrew (p. 36). Eisenbrauns.

An example of an indirect object:
אני נותן לאמא את השמלה
I am giving the mother the dress
אמא mother is the indirect object.
